# Extracting changing XPath in Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm finding it difficulty in extracting the ( changing) XPath text in the final result page.
This website : **http://dgftcom.nic.in/licasp/IecDenQuery.asp**
Few IEC sample Codes are

1. 0504057006 ---> This yields result such as **FIRM** name
2. 0504057007 ---> This yields Invalid IEC code message
3. 0504057006
4. 0504057007
5. 0504057006

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Sub EntityList()

   Dim bot As WebDriver
   Dim count As Long

   Set bot = New WebDriver
   bot.Start "Chrome"
   count = 1
   While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)

   bot.Get "http://dgftcom.nic.in/licasp/IecDenQuery.asp"
   bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='IEC']").SendKeys Range("A" & count)
   bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='submit'][@name='B1']").Click

   Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/font/strong").Text
   'Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]").Text

   bot.Wait 1000

   count = count + 1
   Wend
   bot.Quit
   End Sub
   ```

The issue here is, when the next IEC code is entered, there is a change in the XPath, and this is where the whole code ends abruptly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following XPath.

```
//font[contains(.,'IEC :')]
```

**Code**:

```
Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//font[contains(.,'IEC :')]").Text
```

Comment: Sir, that's Genius !
Could you please explain me briefly ?
I was thinking of trying "if" and "OR" techniques.

Comment: @AmitShah : Checking the string `IEC :` contains  inside `font` tag  which is fixed for valid or invalid code on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

There are one of two combinations based on whether results table has results. You can use css Or syntax. Should be faster than xpath

```
Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByCss("table td, table + font").Text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your support from the beginning and going forward , i have seen a steady growth in my coding skills , but whenever i come to Stack Overflow i feel ashamed of asking questions.
It is guys like you who give encourage such coders to strive for more.
I didn't know much around CSS , after your answer i have been into it since 4-5 hours.

Comment: No need to feel ashamed for asking questions provided you do attempt research and share your efforts. You can learn more about css here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference